# TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to port a Python2 script (which works perfectly) to Python3, but I have a problem.

This is my code:

```
def encode_script(duck_text, duck_lang, bunny=None):

    lang_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'languages')
    language_dict = os.path.join(lang_dir, '{0}.json'.format(duck_lang))
    lang_file = json.load(open(language_dict))
    encoded_file = parse_text(duck_text, lang_file, bunny)

    if encoded_file and not bunny:
        if 'Not in Language' in encoded_file:
            return encoded_file
        else:
            try:
                encoded_file = "".join(encoded_file)
                duck_blob = io.StringIO()

                duck_blob.write(encoded_file.decode('hex'))

                duck_bin = duck_blob.getvalue()
                duck_blob.close()
                return duck_bin

            except Exception as e:
                print ("Error creating inject.bin: {0}".format(e))
                return False
```

and this is the error:

```
D:\encdec\Encoders-decoders\DuckToolkit-master>python ducktools.py -e -l us test.txt ducky.bin
[+] Reading Input file.
  [-] Encoding File
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ducktools.py", line 58, in <module>
    duck_bin = encoder.encode_script(duck_text, language)
  File "D:\encdec\Encoders-decoders\DuckToolkit-master\ducktoolkit\encoder.py", line 160, in encode_script
    encoded_file = parse_text(duck_text, lang_file, bunny).decode()
  File "D:\encdec\Encoders-decoders\DuckToolkit-master\ducktoolkit\encoder.py", line 24, in parse_text
    duck_text = duck_text.replace("\r", "")
TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object
```

The script works perfect on Python2.
What should I do?

Comment: the problem isn't in the code you're showing. The problem is that `duck_text` is a bytes object, because you probably read it using `"rb"` (binary mode).

Comment: Yes, this is the line: duck_text = open(input_file, 'rb').read() What should I do? If i remove 'rb' i get another error:                                                   
File "D:\encdec\Encoders-decoders\DuckToolkit-master\ducktoolkit\encoder.py", line 160, in encode_script
    encoded_file = parse_text(duck_text, lang_file, bunny).decode()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: you've got another error _futher in the execution_. So it's better. I don't know what parse_text is but it's returning a list, so you cannot decode it.

Comment: parse_text is a function. Can I post here the link to the Github project that I'm trying to port? It's not big.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but I was having the same issue when converting a statement with .replace() from python2 to python3 and was able to fix it by prepending 'b' before the arguments in .replace() so try changing:

```
duck_text = duck_text.replace("\r", "")
```

to:

```
duck_text = duck_text.replace(b"\r", b"")
```